# Implicit Conversion of Case Classes Issues

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I am trying to implicitly convert one case class to another case class, but cannot get the code to work.  My editor is giving me the error that Seq[LegacyPhase] doesn't convert to expected Seq[Phase].  Can anyone point me in the direction?  Thanks in advance!

```
implicit def legacyToDashboardBrand(brand: LegacyDashboardBrand)(implicit session: Session): DashboardBrand = {
  val phaseSeq: Seq[Phase] = (for { phaseDataset <- dashboardPhasesQ if phaseDataset.brandId === brand.id
  } yield phaseDataset).list.toSeq
  DashboardBrand(id = brand.id, projectId = brand.projectId, name = brand.name, currentPhase = brand.currentPhase, phases = phaseSeq)
}

implicit def legacyToDashboardPhase(phase: LegacyPhase): Phase = {
  Phase(id = phase.id, brandId = phase.brandId, title = phase.title, steps = Seq())
}
```

Edit: If I do the second implicit conversion line in the first implicit conversion definition it works.

```
implicit def legacyToDashboardBrand(brand: LegacyDashboardBrand)(implicit session: Session): DashboardBrand = {
  val legacyPhaseSeq = (for { 
    phaseDataset <- dashboardPhasesQ if phaseDataset.brandId === brand.id
  } yield phaseDataset).list.toSeq
  val phaseSeq: Seq[Phase] = legacyPhaseSeq.map(phase => 
    Phase(id = phase.id, brandId = phase.brandId, title = phase.title, steps = Seq())
  )

  DashboardBrand(id = brand.id, projectId = brand.projectId, name = brand.name, currentPhase = brand.currentPhase, phases = phaseSeq)
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the exact error ? What is `dashboardPhasesQ` ?

Comment: Hey, Peter.  dashboardPhasesQ is a table query.  val dashboardPhasesQ = TableQuery[LegacyPhaseTable]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second solution (with the duplicated code) works because you explicitly convert the `Seq[LegacyPhase]` to a `Seq[Phase]`.

You could achieve the same result, by adding an implicit parameter in your first`legacyToDashboardBrand` function for your `LegacyPhase => Phase` conversion function :

```
implicit def legacyToDashboardBrand(
  brand: LegacyDashboardBrand
)(implicit 
  session: Session,
  phaseConv: LegacyPhase => Phase
): DashboardBrand = {
  val phaseSeq: Seq[Phase] = (for { 
    phaseDataset <- dashboardPhasesQ if phaseDataset.brandId === brand.id
  } yield phaseDataset).list.map(phaseConv).toSeq
  DashboardBrand(
    id = brand.id, projectId = brand.projectId, name = brand.name,
    currentPhase = brand.currentPhase, phases = phaseSeq
  )
}
```

This way your `LegacyDashboardBrand => DashboardBrand` conversion function, uses your `LegacyPhase => Phase` conversion function.

Note: I don't think that it is a good idea to query a database in a implicit conversion function. Implicit conversions are quite "magical" themselves and make your code more difficult to understand, adding side effects like querying a database would only make it more magical.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, Peter, but that yields the same results as before... it's not converting it still.

Comment: We can use the implicitly passed `phaseConv` to map the `LegacyPhases`, see update.

Comment: Thanks, Peter, that works now.  Any idea why it wouldn't work in the first case?  And trust me, I understand where you're coming from with the implicits

Comment: I have an implicit conversion `LegacyPhase => Phase` in scope, not a  `List[LegacyPhase] => List[Phase]`. We could have added such a conversion too, but if we only use that conversion here, we can just use `map(phaseConv)`.